# Rake db:migrate updates schema.rb, but not Mysql table. Any ideas why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, migration, rake, devise

I'm trying to implement Devise for Ruby on Rails. The install went fine, but when I go to do the first migration (to add a Users table to my mySql database), it fails.

The rake task shows no errors, and in fact displays info about the tables being created, including the time taken to do so.

But my database is still showing the previous migration number, and the new Users table has not been added.

My Schema.rb, however, shows the updated schema.

Has anyone encountered this before, or can shed any light?

Thanks so much!

Comment: Are you sure that you're looking at the right database?